# Redirect output (to file) from Maven dependency in Java

Tags: java, maven, io-redirection, heideltime

In my project, I'm working with the [HeidelTime framework](https://github.com/HeidelTime/heideltime), that I included as a Maven dependency. This framework is very verbose, so I would like to **redirect its output to a file** (but not all outputs from my application). The constraints are the following:

- HeidelTime uses a Logger (Log4J), so I can't simply redirect the standard output to a file.
- I can't access the logger because it's private to the main class (`HeidelTimeStandalone.java`).
- I included HeidelTime in my project as a Maven dependency and I prefer to keep it as is (even if I could download the code and modify directly the source code to make the logger public...)
- Finally, I don't want to simply redirect all outputs (`java -jar myApplication.jar > file.txt`) because I would like to preserve my standard output apart from HeidelTime's output...

Does anybody have an idea to redirect HeidelTime's output in a file? Hope this at least is possible!

Comment: In Log4j you can configure the log level for different loggers. So you can define the log level differently for loggers coming from the Java packages of HeidelTime.

Comment: @JFabianMeier thanks for your interesting answer, I will try to do something with Log4J!

Comment: I still need some help if possible. I tried to set the HeidelTime's logger to Level.OFF but Heideltime continues to be verbose, like if `Logger.getLogger(de.unihd.dbs.heideltime.standalone.HeidelTimeStandalone.class).setLevel(Level.OFF);` didn't work. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turning off the heideltime's logger can be achieved like this (taken from https://github.com/HeidelTime/heideltime/issues/86)

```
HeidelTimeStandalone heidelTime = new HeidelTimeStandalone();

java.util.logging.logger htLogger = java.utillogging.LogManager.getLogManager().getLogger("HeidelTimeStandalone");
    htLogger.setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);

heidelTime = new HeidelTimeStandalone(
    Language.ENGLISH,
    DocumnetType.NARRATIVES,
    OutputType.TIMEML,
    "./config.props",
    POSTagger.NO);
```